# Is 'Joshua' a proper English name for an atheist?

Tags: names

I'm a radical atheist from China, or to be specific, a Marxist.

When I first tried to look up the dictionary to find myself an English name, I thought that 'Joshua' would be a good choice since it sounds like my Chinese name.

After I got to learn more about its religious meaning, I wonder if people with Christian beliefs would feel offended that an atheist names himself Joshua.

Comment: I am a Christian who is proud to be named Joshua because of who I am named after, but I am not offended if you choose to take this name.  I would imagine most people who stand for Christ would be more offended by your doctrines than your name...  A rose by any other name.

Comment: You will find that most English speakers don't interpret a person's name as *meaning* anything, other than just the word(s) to use to refer to that person. A great many people simply choose a name that sounds good to them. It is also common to make up a name. There are any number of reasons to choose a name, and no one can know (and most won't care) why *you* chose a particular name. Joshua is fine. (Incidentally, I would think it's a bit more of a Jewish name than a Christian one, if religion is involved.)

Comment: Whether people would be offended is down to individual propensity to take offence. Many people may find it notably *unusual* that someone would select, for themselves, a name which has strong associations with a family of religions that they do not espouse, and you might have one or two awkward conversations. I'd be surprised if there was any greater intensity of reaction than that.

Comment: Generally, people are named by their parents. You could have grown up an atheist even though they named you with a religious name. It would not be odd. Thus, the name you choose for yourself doesn't have to reflect your atheism, either. And if what I have seen is anything to go by, people will realise that your English name is an approximation of your Chinese name anyway and attach no further significance.

Comment: I'e known plenty of atheist Joshuas (normally shortened to Josh -- are you OK with that) and plenty of religious people.  When a person from China takes on a western name, it's not always recognised that they chose that name for themself anyway; if someone didn't realise it was your choice they wouldn't criticise you for it.

Comment: Don't take name meanings too literally. Or at all literally. But do concern yourself with associations. 'Adolf' doesn't mean anything at all (unless you do the scholarship) but is not a good name to choose because of its bad associations.

Comment: As John Y notes, the etymology of names is at best a curiosity to most. Many people are named after family members, historical figures, or celebrities. Parents who strive for "unique" names very frequently fall victim to fads (e.g. *Noah* is very popular for American boys now, but a few years ago it was *Lucas*, then *Aiden*…). Many Biblical and saint names have meanwhile lost all connection to religion. Basically, someone named *Joshua* wouldn't be expected to have any particular relationship to religion any more than someone named *Cooper* would be expected to be skilled in barrel-making.

Comment: There are plenty of Spanish speakers named Jesús who aren't religious.

Comment: Google for "famous atheists", and you get names like Richard Dawkins, Sam Harris, Christopher Hitchens, Daniel Dennett, Michael Shermer, Peter Singer. I've heard many people attack them, but I've not heard anyone, Christian or not, complain about their names (and all these first names are of Judeo-Christian exctraction).

Answer (score 2):

As a die-hard atheist (what many would call a *militant atheist*), I think you can call yourself anything you like.  There are some names -- *Adolph* comes to mind -- that you might want to avoid, primarily because of the negative associations most people have about them and, by extension, might have about you.

Would you be offended by someone who was *not* a Marxist (and in fact is Christian) having the name Karl?

If someone *is* offended, that's their issue.  They would be welcome to decide they don't want to be your friend, but that would be their loss.  You don't need to live your life according to their rules -- only they need to do that.

My youngest son is named Ezra which is biblical; there's a whole book of Ezra.  My wife and mother-in-law who pushed for that name (atheist and more-or-less deist, both culturally Jewish) had no idea of its biblical significance -- I found it quite hilarious to point out, once it was too late to change it, that the book of Ezra basically condemned my parents' marriage.  (They should have let me pick the name -- Tuolumne is a perfectly good name!)

Similarly, I suspect that there are a lot of Christians out there who couldn't tell you who Joshua was or what he did in the bible.  (All I know, I'll admit, is that "*Joshua fit the battle at Jericho ... and the walls came a-tumblin' down*", thanks to the song about it.)

Also, this applies only to the US (where I am).  Other places ([Sweden is one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_law_in_Sweden)**) may have rules about names.  (Though they likely wouldn't apply to foreigners.)

** Thanks to @Mitch for pointing out that the rules in Sweden apply only to new names.  (I remembered writing an article about it a long time ago, but had forgotten the details.)

Comment: Re Sweden, the rules about names are only about new names and has nothing to do at all whether the name fits the personality or thoughts of the named or the situation.

Comment: Sure enough. In Germany they have a similar official 'naming' bureau. The OP seems to be coming from a particular assumption, and I didn't want them to get the idea that Swedish somehow fits the assumption (it doesn't and really none of the European languages have transparent name meanings). Some cultures/languages do (Hebrew, Chinese) so there is the possibility of choosing names with meaning. Also, many East Asians, for many reasons, pick an English name and they want it to sound right. But English just doesn't do the meaning thing.